Custom properties possible for individual path points?
I am working on a small script that turns Blender into a kind of level editor and can import and export Bezier paths from CSV information into Blender. However, these CSVs contain custom properties for the curve object and for each of the individual points.
Curve objects can contain custom properties in Blender, but this does not seem to be possible for the individual points of the paths. Blender stores some values per point, but only 3, namely the Tilt, Radius and Weight values. But I would need 8 integer values for each point.
Therefore I ask if there is another way to give path points custom properties? Possibly via a plugin?
